# Flutter - Login screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a login screen in Flutter. This login connect to e-mail and password, but have some problems. The errors revolves around the object was given an infinite size during layout. Attached is the code for my Dart class and the logged errors when running the code.

What are you guys getting out of the error code I cannot resolve?

**Dart class**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class FormContainer extends StatelessWidget {


  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(
      builder: (context, child, model) {
        if (model.isLoading)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white),
                  controller: _passController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: "WorkSansLight", fontSize: 18.0),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white24,
                    hintText: "E-mail",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (text){
                    if(text.isEmpty || !text.contains("@")) return "E-mail inválido!";
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white),
                  controller: _passController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: "WorkSansLight", fontSize: 18.0),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white24,
                    hintText: "Senha",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.lock_outline,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                  validator: (text){
                    if(text.isEmpty || text.length < 6) return "Senha inválida!";
                  },
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      if(_emailController.text.isEmpty)
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text("Insira seu e-mail para recuperação!"),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            )
                        );
                      else {
                        model.recoverPass(_emailController.text);
                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text("Confira seu e-mail!"),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                              duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            )
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Esqueci minha senha",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
                    ),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  child: new FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                    child: Text(
                      "Entrar",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                      }
                      model.signIn(
                          email: _emailController.text,
                          pass: _passController.text,
                          onSuccess: _onSuccess,
                          onFail: _onFail
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
    );
  }

  void _onSuccess() {
    // Navigator.of(context).pop(); Esta dando erro
  }

  void _onFail() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text("Falha ao Entrar!"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**Errors**

```
  I/flutter ( 4207): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():  
  I/flutter ( 4207): RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
  I/flutter ( 4207): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside
 another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
  I/flutter ( 4207): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is: RenderIndexedSemantics#dc596
 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
  I/flutter ( 4207):   creator: IndexedSemantics ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← 
  I/flutter ( 4207):   AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverList ← SliverPadding ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#aaf31] ←
  I/flutter ( 4207):   Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
  I/flutter ( 4207):   RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1430c] ←
  I/flutter ( 4207):   parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)
  I/flutter ( 4207):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  I/flutter ( 4207):   semantic boundary
  I/flutter ( 4207):   size: Size(360.0, Infinity)
  I/flutter ( 4207):   index: 0
  I/flutter ( 4207): The constraints that applied to the RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox were:
  I/flutter ( 4207):   BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  I/flutter ( 4207): The exact size it was given was:
  I/flutter ( 4207): Size(360.0, Infinity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
import 'package:loja_virtual/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual/widgets/sign_up_button.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class NewLoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewLoginScreenState createState() => _NewLoginScreenState();
}

class _NewLoginScreenState extends State<NewLoginScreen> {
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(
        builder: (context, child, model) {
          if (model.isLoading)
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("images/background1.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "images/user1.png",
                              width: 130,
                              height: 130,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            controller: _emailController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: "WorkSansLight",
                                  fontSize: 15.0),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white24,
                              hintText: "E-mail",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.email,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            validator: (text) {
                              if (text.isEmpty || !text.contains("@"))
                                return "E-mail inválido!";
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            controller: _passController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: "WorkSansLight",
                                  fontSize: 15.0),
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.white24,
                              hintText: "Senha",
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(90.0)),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white24, width: 0.5)),
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                Icons.lock_outline,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            obscureText: true,
                            validator: (text) {
                              if (text.isEmpty || text.length < 6)
                                return "Senha inválida!";
                            },
                          ),
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (_emailController.text.isEmpty)
                                  _scaffoldKey.currentState
                                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "Insira seu e-mail para recuperação!"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                  ));
                                else {
                                  model.recoverPass(_emailController.text);
                                  _scaffoldKey.currentState
                                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                    content: Text("Confira seu e-mail!"),
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                                    duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                  ));
                                }
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                "Esqueci minha senha",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13.0),
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 80,
                            width: 80,
                            child: new FloatingActionButton(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                              child: Text(
                                "Entrar",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {}
                                model.signIn(
                                    email: _emailController.text,
                                    pass: _passController.text,
                                    onSuccess: _onSuccess,
                                    onFail: _onFail);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          SignUpButton()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onSuccess() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _onFail() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Falha ao Entrar!"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
    ));
  }
}
```

> Now it's Ok. thx

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygEOl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your ScopedModelDescendant in a Flexible (or a container with fixed size). By itself, it doesn't have any concept of what size it needs to be, so you need it to be a child of something that does have size constraints.